# retrieve account object in stripe and respond with bank_account or card

Tags: php, stripe-payments

When calling retrieveExternalAccount from the API I'd like a response of whether or not the stripe connected account is a card or bank_account and then list the last 4 digits of account or card accordingly.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_account_cards/retrieve

```
require_once 'stripe-php-master/init.php';
//$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient($STRIPE_API_KEY);

$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
    $STRIPE_API_KEY
);
$link = $stripe->accounts->retrieve(
    $STRIPE_DEST,
    []
);

$linkaccount = $stripe->accounts->retrieveExternalAccount(
   $STRIPE_DEST,
   $linkaccount->id,
   []
);

if ($link->transfers_enabled == FALSE){
echo '<script>top.location.href = "https://www.website.net/oa-drive.php"</script>';
exit();
}

if ($linkaccount->object == "bank_account"){
$accounttype = 'account ending in '.$linkaccount->last4.'';
} else {
$accounttype .= 'card ending in '.$linkaccount->last4.'';
}
```

Comment: `$linkaccount` is undefined, when accessing property `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't ask what your problem is, I can assume from the code that the problem is the empty response from the `retrieveExternalAccount` method.
You should pass to this metod the [ID of the account to which the external account belongs](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/c704949c49b72985c76cc61063aa26fefbd2724e/lib/Account.php#L313) and [the ID of the external account to retrieve](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/c704949c49b72985c76cc61063aa26fefbd2724e/lib/Account.php#L314).

Comment: I added $linkaccount->id to pass the ID however I still am getting an empty response.

Comment: And what **value** are you passing?

Comment: According to documentation I should be passing id and account 'id' and 'account'.

Comment: When you pass `id` property of `linkaccount` object, what is its value? Why are you passing a `linkaccount` object property to retrieve that object?